# org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController NOT Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using Netbeans.

[image: Imports]

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
```

Unable to use this. What has it been changed to or what should I use? Learning Spring now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using Spring version 4 and the SimpleFormController class was [removed](https://issues.openmrs.org/browse/TRUNK-4607).

You should use [@Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) annotation for your controller beans instead. Check [Spring WebMVC docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)